# UIAutomation in ios

Tags: iphone, ios-ui-automation

I am new to the UIAutomation in iPhone.I have a login screen.In my login screen there are two textfields and a login button. I need to provide a script with following purpose.

The script should,

- Enter a correct username & password, and assert that the user is
  taken to taxies nearby page
- Enter a correct username & wrong password, and assert that the user is shown the alert  message as expected, and user stays back on the same page.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I see you've had several questions on UIAutomation, and are already aware of Apple's documentation. Here's another great resource that might help: http://pragprog.com/book/jptios/test-ios-apps-with-ui-automation. The book is still in beta, but I have it and it's very handy. Disclaimer: I know the author, but I'm not shilling his book because of that. Also, there are several WWDC videos and slides in the past few years that discuss UIAutomation. Not sure of the session numbers though.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Instruments
2. Select Automation
3. Choose your target with the pulldown at the top next to [pause, record, Record Once]
4. Under the scripts section on the left, select add, then create
5. Hit the record button.
6. Now click around and enter the correct username and password.

This should get you started. See where you get from there.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else needs this, here is my script for it. Correct signin function will be similar.

```
function wrongSignIn() {
    // Assume you are on the signin page already
    var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
    var appWindow = target.frontMostApp().mainWindow();
    // Assume you name the text fields username/password and they are accessible
    appWindow.textFields()["username"].setValue("correct username");
    appWindow.textFields()["password"].setValue("wrong password");
    // Assume you have a button called "Sign in"
    appWindow.buttons()["Sign in"].tap();

    // Probably you need some delay for the UI to appear
    target.delay(3);
    var alert = target.frontMostApp().alert();
    // Make sure the alert is on screen with right message, and stay on old screen
    if (alert.checkIsValid() && alert.name() == "Wrong password!" 
                             && appWindow.name() == "Sign in") {
        UIALogger.logPass("Pass the wrong signin test.");
    } else {
        UIALogger.logFail("Fail the wrong signin test.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change it to

appWindow.secureTextFields()["password"].setValue("wrong Password");

And as Roderic explained, you can record the scripts as well and save them for later use.